# How to wire a Backbone View to a meteor handlebars template?

Tags: backbone.js, meteor, handlebars.js

Looks like Backbone.view, meteor and handlebars have overlap functionality when it comes to manipulating a section of the DOM. I looked at the ToDo app which is suppose to use Backbone, but in reality, they only use the Router.

Backbone views also deal with templates... but they sound so different from meteor templates. Besides, it looks like both backbone & meteor can update the ui on a model update.

ok, I am lost!? Who does what?

Is Backbone really useful for a Meteor App? Can Backbone & Handle bars coexist?
and if they can, in the Meteor context, how to wire a Backbone view to a handlebars template?

EDIT: found the todo-backbone example. it seems to confirm that you can go either:

- meteor + backbone + underscore templates
- or... meteor + handlebars

meteor+backbone+handlebars doesn't seem like a viable option...

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's very easy and no more work than using the Underscore template.  Here's an example .html file:

```
<template name="user_list">
<ul>
  {{#each users}}
  <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>
```

And here's an example .js file:

```
Users = new Meteor.collection("users");

if (Meteor.is_client) {
  Template.user_list.users = function() {
    return Users.find();
  }

  window.UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },
    template: function() {
      Meteor.ui.render(function() {
        return Template.user_list();
      });
    },
    render: function() {
      $(el).empty().append(this.template());
    }
  });
}
```

You can then use a Router or another View to manage when you want to display the UserView just like you would in any other Backbone.js app.

The key is to use the Meteor.ui.render or other Meteor.ui method to render the HTML so that it's reactive.

Comment: I wonder why they brought Backbone as part of meteor, it's very confusing. BB and M share a lot of features. In the example above, how can I use a BB.model and still have it seen as a M.collection ?

Comment: The models in Meteor are much more full featured than Backbone's providing reactivity and out of the box synchronization across clients whereas Backbone's concept of Models and Collections are mostly a way to structure calls back to a server and then provide a templated way to architect event based systems.  So while you could retrofit Meteor collections and models into Backbone's, I'd recommend against it.  Instead, use Meteor the way it's meant to be used.